# How does insider trading law affect bitcoin exchanges?

Tags: finance, cryptocurrency, insider-trading

The Bitcoin network is predicated on the premise that it is difficult to find 'low' hash values for a given input. This is an incredibly safe bet because of the way the algorithm is implemented - if you change one byte in the input then the output changes to an (apparently) random number without any way to predict what it could be in advance.

People can 'mine' for new bitcoin by taking existing blocks and trying to 'solve' them by looking for a particularly low hash value. Currently this is done by simply trying lots of input values until a low enough output is hit by chance. Huge 'farms' and pools of computing power and specialised hardware exist to mine the new bitcoin and by all accounts only just manage to turn a profit after the cost of powering them.

So suppose someone somewhere discovers the hashing algorithm the Bitcoin network uses is not as random as the world thinks and comes up with a new unlocking algorithm that can reliably produce low hash values and 'solve a block' in seconds on his beat up pentium III computer at home (I realise that this is almost certainly impossible but it's a hypothetical).

He, and only he, then knows the secret and has the power to create new bitcoin quickly. Would there be legal implications for him to use this new knowledge to his advantage and to the detriment of others by, for example,

1. Generating new bitcoin and accumulating it just slowly enough to avoid arousing suspicion
2. After a period suddenly dumping and short-selling as much as he can before going public with the news of his algorithm (which would surely suddenly devalue the currency to the point of collapse)

Obviously he would be on safe ground if he just started using his new algorithm to generate bitcoin - nothing in the rules about *how* blocks are solved.

My suspicion is that as soon as he uses that algorithm to deliberately influence the exchange for the currency for his own profit (which he arguably does by 'going slow' in stage 1 but *certainly* does by timing the dumping/short selling just before the announcement in stage 2) then he must be violating some law, such as some kind of ban on insider trading?

Comment: @Dawn Yeah, i know - hence our hero's slowly slowly approach in stage 1 - he doesn't want the difficulty to adjust enough to knock out too many other nodes and raise suspicion (they drop out on basis if difficulty increases then profitability decreases - weakest can no longer make a profit and stop)

Comment: I think you can fix that hypothetical like this: assume that the person has found a flaw in the bitcoin algorithm that would destroy the security of the blockchain. Suppose releasing this proof would lower the value of bitcoin. Then the rest of your question makes sense. You are basically asking if having unique access to information that would lower bitcoin's value prohibits you from buying or selling bitcoins before making that information public.

Comment: @Dawn In the long term, yes, But difficulty adjustments only take place every fortnight so there would be a huge glut in that first period (and probably a few subsequent ones as a balance was reached) and a devastating impact on confidence in the currency so the collapse would still be inevitable, no?

Comment: @Dawn - sorry - we crossed comments. Your latest one is a fair summary of my question

Comment: I'd be a a little reluctant to cut out huge chunks. I also want to know if the deliberately 'going slow' is questionable too

Comment: I'll try to make an edit that gets to the core of your question, including the going slow part. Feel free to correct if I get it wrong.

Comment: What laws?  Are bitcoins securities?  Are they traded on regulated markets?  What could make a person a "bitcoin insider?"  Is your question actually, "When is it illegal to engage in commerce with the benefit of non-public information?"

Comment: @feetwet Your comment may now be obsolete. Somewhen in the past 4 years, Bitcoin seemingly found itself under the CFTC's umbrella. And the CFTC is going after insider traders now — partly due to allegations that people close to Trump are using leaks to make a profit in the oil markets, so it seems.

Answer (score 4):

Your question assumes that there is a method to find a block of bitcoins with a faster computation than the brute force method used so far.

If such a faster calculation method exists, it is proprietary to the mathematics and our superhero has not invented it, he just discovered it and used it. It is not an insider trading case since everybody has the possibility to acquire the same math knowledge for free and use the same super algorithm (and maybe is using it already). Insider trading covers only situations when an insider has an information earlier than the market due his proximity to the information, being e.g. employee of the relevant company whose shares are traded, etc. Insider trading presumes that the insider is an "insider", i.e. has the information earlier only due to his position. On the other hand, having an information earlier due to his math skills which are available to everybody does not constitute insider trading.

Using the new discovered super algorithm for shorting the bitcoin price is not illegal since the super algorithm is not illegal either, but proprietary to the mathematics. The assumption that the price will drop may be not true, it is only a valid speculation.

Comment: "It is not an insider trading case" are you sure that it true in every jurisdiction?  Insider trading laws may be designed to stop "insiders", but depending on the exact wording of the law the OP's example may or may not caught by the laws (and remember that the judge that tries the case will be a lawyer, not a mathematician).

Comment: @MartinBonner Bitcoin is not a *security,* it is a form of *currency.* An algorithm is not specific, privileged/non-public knowledge, it is a complex mathematical computation typically applied or expressed in a programmatic fashion (which is the only reason algorithms themselves can't be patented in the US - because math can't be patented.) The discovery of the algorithm is just that, a discovery like fire or the wheel. The application of it might potentially be considered intellectual property. Zeroing out cryptocurrency in this fashion could be described as a weakness of the technology.

Comment: @OpenSorceress You seem to be assuming your categorization will be accepted in every jurisdiction.  I see no evidence of that.

Comment: @MartinBonner Well, I suppose I have no evidence. All I have is this determination from the SEC. https://www.sec.gov/news/public-statement/statement-clayton-2017-12-11

Comment: My point is that the SEC operates under the traditions of the American legal system.  Other legal systems can be *very* different.

Comment: @MartinBonner It would seem to me very odd to have a law anywhere that says that, if I come up with an improved process for something and use it, I'm guilty of insider trading.  It would make having trade secrets illegal.  I'm not saying that there isn't a country that requires revealing of all trade secrets in use, but I'd have to be told of one to believe it.

Comment: @MartinBonner an improved calculation of a bitcoin block can be hardly illegal as insider trading in any jurisdiction, since it can not be proven that nobody else uses or could not use the improved algorithm as well. Any market participants who do not use the best possible mathematical algorithm can not claim that they could not use it, since it is proprietary to mathematics and not to the superHero who was only one of those who discovered it. It is like blaming the naturally smart securities trader with the best "gut feeling" of a misuse of his intelligence.

Comment: @OpenSorceress Bitcoin is actually more a commodity than a currency. It is even classified as commodity by many regulators in many countries. The reason: (i) bitcoin has too wide spread between buy and sell, (ii) it can not be used as value measure due to its high volatility and (iii) its acceptance by general public is limited.

Comment: @MartinBonner I was thinking about it from the perspective of IP, as this is an innovation, since IP has reciprocity between most of the countries in the world at least to a point.

Comment: The algorithm may not be "insider", but what about the knowledge that *someone has discovered* the algorithm?